# How to create report designer with case attribute?

Tags: acumatica

[Problem with count case in caseclass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3ZKR.png)

I used three tables when I created this report: `CRCase`, `CRCaseClass` and `CSAnswer`.

But when I want to count the cases in `caseclass`, it gets this problem.

Comment: What's the problem, could you please clarify or be more specific?

Comment: I mean if I create case 2 in CaseClass ABC and in CaseClass I have 2 attributes: OS, and Product. So  case1 and case2 have both attributes. But when I count case in class it should 2cases not 4cases.